# RxJava: Issue with withLatestFrom operator when using in combination with .subScribeOn

Tags: kotlin, rx-java, rx-java2

Please find the below kotlin code snippet:

```
val dummyApi: PublishSubject<String> = PublishSubject.create()

fun withLatestFromtest() {
    dummyApi.onNext("1")
    getOtherObservable().withLatestFrom(dummyApi)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribeBy(
                    onNext = {
                        Log.e("TAG", "Pair ${it.first} /// ${it.second}")
                    },
                    onError = {
                        it.printStackTrace()
                    },
                    onComplete = {
                        Log.e("TAG", "Pair2 Complete")
                    }
            )
    dummyApi.onNext("2")
    dummyApi.onNext("3")
}

private fun getOtherObservable(): Observable<String>{
    return Observable.just("API")
            .delay(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
}
```

Expected Output -

```
Pair API /// 3
Pair2 Complete
```

Actual Output -

```
Pair2 Complete
```

When I removed **.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())** it worked as expected. I am not able to understand why scheduler is creating the issue.

Comment: `subscribeOn` delays the subscription to `dummyApi` a tiny bit and thus the execution rushes through `withLatestFromtest` and no `onNext` will reach the `withLatestFrom` operator in time.